NestJS: Error Thrown Not Propagating to Frontend, Returns 200 Status Instead
I am working on a NestJS application where I have a controller method that fetches new users from DB. During this process, an error should be thrown under certain conditions. But my frontend desktop app receives a 200 status without the error message. Interestingly, the error is correctly propagated when tested via Swagger or Postman.
(@nestjs/swagger": "^6.1.3")
Is there a problem with the code or I just don't understand how the errors are processed? Here is the code from the controller to the repository:
My Controller:
@ApiQuery({
    name: 'offset',
    type: 'number',
    required: false,
})
@ApiQuery({
    name: 'limit',
    type: 'number',
    required: false,
})
@ApiQuery({
    name: 'sort',
    type: 'string',
    required: false,
})
@ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
    description: 'The server refuses to authorize the request.',
})
@ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
    description: 'The request is malformed or invalid.',
})
@ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
    description: 'The server did not find anything matching the request.',
})
@ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
    description: 'The client did not produce a request within the expected time.',
})
@ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    description: 'The server encountered an unexpected condition.',
})
@Get('users/new-registrations')
async getNewRegistrations(
    @Query() { offset = 0, limit = 50, sort }:
        { offset: number, limit: number, sort?: string },
): Promise<RegistrationsResponseDto | void> {
        const dto = new RegQueryOptionsDto();
        dto.offset = offset;
        dto.limit = limit;
        dto.sort = sort;
        return await this.registrationService.getNewRegistrations(dto);
}

My service:
async getNewRegistrations(
    dto: RegQueryOptionsDto,
): Promise<RegistrationsResponseDto | void> {
    const adminId = 0;
    const product = 0;

    await this.isRegQueueLocked(adminId, product);
    return await this.fetchNewRegistrations(dto, adminId, product);
}

async isRegQueueLocked(adminId: string, product: Product): Promise<void> {
    const lockTime = 30000; //30secs
    const lockedByAdminId = await this.usersRepository.getAdminIdIfRegistrationsLocked(adminId, lockTime, product);
    if (lockedByAdminId !== null && lockedByAdminId !== adminId) {
        await this.throwExceptionWithAdminData(lockedByAdminId);
    }
}

My repository:
async getAdminIdIfRegistrationsLocked(
    adminId: string,
    lockTime: number,
    product: Product,
): Promise<string | null> {
    const registrationQueueEntity: RegistrationQueueEntity | null =
        await this.registrationQueueRepository.findOne({
            where: {
                product,
            },
        });
    if (registrationQueueEntity &&
        registrationQueueEntity.lockedTimestamp &&
        registrationQueueEntity.lockedByUser
    ) {
        if (Date.now() < (Number(registrationQueueEntity.lockedTimestamp) || 0) + lockTime) {
            return registrationQueueEntity.lockedByUser;
        } else if (registrationQueueEntity.lockedByUser === adminId) {
            await this.unlockNewRegistrations(adminId, product); //If I remove this line, error is thrown correctly
            throw new Error('REG_QUE_LOCK_INACTIVITY'); //408
        }
    }
    return null;
}

Problem:
When the condition to throw new Error('REG_QUE_LOCK_INACTIVITY') is met, my desktop app receives a 200 status code without any error message, while the error is correctly shown in Swagger or Postman. Why is this discrepancy happening, and how can I ensure that the error is correctly propagated to the frontend?
Any insights on why this might be happening and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

So, I don't know why the error is not thrown, but this is the solution. I added timeout and that works. Maybe it can be done differently too, but this works.
setTimeout(() => {
  this.unlockNewRegistrations(adminId, product);
}, 100);
throw new Error(REG_QUE_LOCK_INACTIVITY);

